# Why do we suppose that reflected quantum state has the same energy that initial state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, reflection

I just read in my lecture notes that the teacher assumed the wave vector $k_+$ of reflected (from potential) state the same (but inverted) as wave vector of initial psi function (that goes to the potential barrier direction), I don't understand why the wave vectors and energies of states have be the same on big distances from barrier.

**Here the screenshot:**
[image: The screenshot from notes]

Comment: Any energy change means an interaction, An interaction means the system should be described by a different wavefunction.

Comment: I didn't get it, there is no "interaction" term in my notes. Btw the past wave has different energy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just understood that this is the consequence of double degeneration in energy for free particles. I just have circumstances where particle on one side have particular energy, so I am allowed only to use two monochromatic waves for this energy. I should not consider this situation like some process of reflection that creates reflected wave from origin single one. There are already two allowed states for particular energy and we are just guessing the coefficients before this states.
The coefficient $R_u$ technically is not the reflection coefficient, it's just shows us ratio between two eigenstates for one single particle, I could put this coefficient before the incoming wave and not reflected with the same success.